# Pgadmin4 installation fails on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver

Tags: 18.04, postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to install pgadmin4 on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver but every time I try to run the

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

it returns the following error:

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pgadmin4-apache2
```

I read almost everything available in SO (e.g. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239607/pgadmin-package-pgadmin4-has-no-installation-candidate/60719329#60719329), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566325/package-pgadmin4-has-no-installation-candidate-for-ubuntu-20-04)) but I always get the above mentioned error.

I do not want to install it by using Docker.
Could someone provide a solution for this?
Thanks!

Comment: `pgadmin4-apache2` is NOT shipped in the Ubuntu repositories.  Likely you have misinformation.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode is a good start for pgadmin4 and getting started on 18.04 with it

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you very much! The truth is, most of the online tutorials point to the pgadmin4-apache2 package, so I was pretty sure this is part of an ubuntu repo. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Then all of those tutorials are wrong.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pgadmin4-apache2&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  Doesn't exist.  Doesn't exist in the upstream repos from Postgres either.

Comment: I"ve provided a tutorial to use the upstream pgadmin4 packages which provide a `pgadmin4-web` package.  Those are not Ubuntu packages, though, they're from a third party repository from Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `pgadmin4-apache2` package.  There never has been.

Upstream Postgres repositories however have a `pgadmin4-web` function though that will make it a webserver like function and configure webserver components.

From the [pgadmin4 download/repositories page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/) come instructions for using their repository:

```
#
# Setup the repository
#

# Install the public key for the repository (if not done previously):
sudo curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add

# Create the repository configuration file:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

#
# Install pgAdmin
#

# Install for both desktop and web modes:
sudo apt install pgadmin4

# Install for desktop mode only:
sudo apt install pgadmin4-desktop

# Install for web mode only: 
sudo apt install pgadmin4-web 

# Configure the webserver, if you installed pgadmin4-web:
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

Desktop mode is as if you are the only user and using it as a desktop GUI on your system to maintain multiple postgres servers and disables authentication on the pgAdmin component so you don't have users, etc. configurable on the pgAdmin component.

Web mode is the 'server' mode and when installed works like phpMyAdmin does, except for Postgres stuff.

Install either mode you wish, but if you're configuring it so that it's served by a webserver, you want `pgadmin4-web` and need to run the configuration program as listed in the last line of their instructions.

**At the time of writing, this works for the following non-EOL and still supported Ubuntu releases**:

- Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic)
- Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)
- Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy, from v4.30)